# Pedestrian routes style

Tags: android, maps, skmaps

Is it possible in SKMaps on Android make pedestrian route style like in Google Maps with dots?

[image: Google Maps Android 9.42.3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use the same dotted routing style. Please check the Pedestrian Navigation UI in our demo project. You can simulate a pedestrian route from Calculate Route(s) > Start Navigation.

Comment: can i get the link to the demo

Comment: You can find our demo projects here: http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download